# What do they mean when say “the French equivalent of a Ph.D.”?

Tags: phd, degree, france

I read the biography of a French-born scientist-turned-entrepreneur Philippe Kahn. It says that Philippe Kahn received the “French equivalent of a Ph.D. certified by the French Academy of Sciences”.

I discovered an article about Kahn which says that he earned the equivalent of a doctorate, but not the degree. In yet another article, I read that he holds an *agregation de mathematiques,* and this is the French equivalent of a doctorate. I am rather baffled at all this, since Wikipedia clearly indicates that *agregation* has nothing to do with the equivalent of a doctorate. Can you explain what Kahn's biographers mean by “the French equivalent of a Ph.D.”? And if this is the degree then why should it be certified by the academy? So far I have come to conclusion that by the equivalent they mean the D.E.A. degree

Comment: Is this question about Khan's biography specifically or about the French education system at the relevant time?

Comment: After reading about Kahn, I became interested in French educational system as well.

Comment: Victor Wortman's article about Kahn says that after completing masters program in Nice, Philippe Kahn studied to get the equivalent of a doctorate, but not the degree, because to get the doctorate would require more years to get. Maybe I should edit my question to add this info too?

Comment: Could you add link to Victor Wortman's article?  I can't find the one you're referring to.

Comment: I have a PDF copy of that article. Can I attach it to comment? I got it some time ago at web.archive.org

Comment: I got it: http://archive.li/q2xY7

Comment: Are you sure that that's the right link?  It says: **"_Pastorale completed, Kahn went to Nice, where he completed a masters program in mathematics. He continued to teach, to study, and to work on university-related projects, in the process accumulating the equivalent of a doctorate, but not the degree.  To earn the doctorate would have required four or five years of serious research, he explains._"**

Comment: [This Wired article](https://www.wired.com/2000/10/kahn/) from 2000 has a claim like what you described: **_In the 1970s, after receiving the equivalent of a PhD in mathematics, in France, Kahn worked on Pascal under Niklaus Wirth in Zurich and was a programmer for the Intel-based Micral, one of the first personal computers._**.

Comment: Victor Wortman's article was what made me initially  think that by "the equivalent" they mean D.E.A.. That is, from the text I deduced that the equivalent must be sth higher than masters and lower than Ph.D., so it had to be DEA. I knew nothing about  Doctorat du 3ème cycle.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [a 1985 biography in *PC Magazine*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Udw3QWX2LQ8C&pg=PA115&lpg=PA115&dq=Philippe+Kahn+%22Ph.D.%22&source=bl&ots=v-vR-j8zew&sig=u08j-Z6jO_fUr2ry-XpVEZpw4xE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirnKeQltnVAhUI02MKHeoVAV0Q6AEIQjAI#v=onepage&q=Philippe%20Kahn%20%22Ph.D.%22&f=false):

> During his college days, Kahn played saxophone in Paris jazz clubs while earning an *Agrégation de mathématique*, **equivalent to a Ph.D. in math.**

Another [1985 *PC Magazine* biography](https://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,1167682,00.asp) states:

> Kahn, who received **the French equivalent of a Ph.D. in mathematics from the French Academy of Sciences,** taught mathematics at the university level in Nice and Grenoble before coming to the United States.

Both [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippe_Kahn) and [Kahn's LinkedIn page](https://www.linkedin.com/in/philippekahn/) state only that he received a master's degree in mathematics from Université Nice Sophia Antipolis in 1975.  This is not the equivalent of a Ph.D., and Sophia Antipolis is nowhere near Paris.

The [*agrégation de mathématiques*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agr%C3%A9gation_de_math%C3%A9matiques) is a [competitive civil service exam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agr%C3%A9gation) used to recruit high school and university mathematics teachers.  While the exam is extremely rigorous, and *agrégés* are qualified to teach at universities, the *agrégation* is not a research degree.  French doctorates underwent [a major reform in 1974](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctorat_en_France#Apr.C3.A8s_1968.2C_l.27unification_des_disciplines) and [again in 1984](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctorat_en_France#La_r.C3.A9forme_de_1984_:_unification_des_dipl.C3.B4mes), but I believe the closest French equivalent of a Ph.D that Kahn could have earned in the late 1970s was the [*Doctorat du 3ème cycle*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctorat_en_France#Doctorat_de_sp.C3.A9cialit.C3.A9_.283e.C2.A0cycle.29).

Comment: Yes, I think that's the only possible explanation.

Comment: I also know of top french researchers who didn't enrolled in any doctoral course but are in fact doctors and directors of research. I was told this is (was?) possible in light of an initial exception made for M. Curie. Obviously the people I know did demonstrate their scientific research competence in a non classical parcour.

Comment: @Alchimista: You may want to add a comment, or maybe even an answer, to this question: [*Has anyone, based on great performance, ever been awarded a higher degree than the one they enrolled for?*](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/93433/has-anyone-based-on-great-performance-ever-been-awarded-a-higher-degree-than-t)

Comment: @O. R. Mapper. Unfortunately I don't know details. I am just sure about it as  I worked in a group lead by one of those scientist but I am not willing to ask her(him). S(he) has not university curriculum at all. I also think that in my country - in principle!!! - an university could appoint a professorship on the sole basis of achievements. I said in principle, and in this case I am not sure.

Comment: But yes, I can add a comment..